# My Silver Monkey X Kagi microphone doesn't work even after meddling with pavucontrol or alsamixer

Tags: sound, 22.04, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

I bought a new mic (Silver Monkey X Kagi) to replace the old one (this time it is an USB mic) and for some godforsaken reason it won't work no matter what.

I tried to get help by browsing other forums but to no avail (I even got an USB to jack adapter). While trying to configure some settings on pavucontrol, I discovered that my audio inputs make white noise even without any microphone. The PC that I am using is pretty old (15 Years!) so i had to install ubuntu because otherwise most of the stuff I'm using wouldn't work.

My sound card is "Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio". I'm not that experienced on Ubuntu (22.04) so if anyone could help me, I would greatly appreciate it!

Posts that I did use advice from:

- https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=207072
- https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=373381
- https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=117006